# Add fields to schema base on conditional checkbox

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to figure out how to best design a Schema base on the value of a checkbox:

```
var weatherSchema = mongoose.Schema({
day: Date,
minTtemperature: Number,
maxTemperature: Number,
snowy: Boolean,
amountOfSnow: Number,
snowAttribute2: String,
snowAttribute3: String

 })
```

What i want to accomplish is to fill Snow attributes only in days where snowy value is True.

I've explored **discriminators** but I think this option is only helpful when I want to add different attributes or schema fields based on the value of an input.
I'll really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that [**`discriminators`**](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html) is probably what you should consider.

Here is why:

1. You will be using model inheritance. Easy to add common fields later on. Your data seems to be dependent on the `type` of day and seems to have common fields (like day, temperature etc) e.g. (sunny, stormy, snowy) so that type descriminator would be helpful.
2. You will have a `descriminator` key lets call it `dayType` with which you can now differentiate the type of days. This will also allow you to easily count/query how many `sunny or snowy` days you had in a date period with ease.
3. Based on that checkbox you can simply `switch` the models from one to the other where each would have its own specific data. Snow days would have `amountOfSnow` etc.

Comment: Thank you @Akrion for explaining this. I'm going to try this approach.

Comment: One question... In my case I have to discriminate base on two checkbox, Can I have more than one key discriminator?